# How can I tell Automapper to try to call the .Value property on source members, not .ToString() on UglySoapXml objects?

Tags: c#, automapper

Consider this class:

```
public class UglyXmlSoapObject {
      public FIRST_NAMETYPESHAPE FIRST_NAMETYPESHAPE { get; set; }

      public LAST_NAMETYPESHAPE LAST_NAMETYPESHAPE { get; set; }

      public DEPT_TAX_CALCTYPESHAPE DEPT_TAX_CALCTYPESHAPE { get; set; }
}

public class FIRST_NAMETYPESHAPE {
      public String Value { get; set; }
}

public class LAST_NAMETYPESHAPE {
      public String Value { get; set; }
}

public class DEPT_TAX_CALCTYPESHAPE {
      public Decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

The XXXX_XXXXXXTYPESHAPE are just wrapper/holder classes that expose a String property (Value).  So to actually get the firstName, you call:

String firstName = uglyXmlObject.FIRST_NAMETYPESHAPE.Value;

How to I tell Automapper to always try to map the .Value property of a given object?  I have dozens of Xml classes that I would like to map as follows:

UglyXmlSource.FIRST_NAMETYPESHAPE.Value   => poco.FirstName
UglyXmlSource.LAST_NAMETYPESHAPE.Value    => poco.LastName

I've figured out that I need a custom naming convention, but then, to get the source member Value, Automapper just calls ToString(), so the value of poco.FirstName winds up being: "AutoMapperDemo.Program+FIRST_NAMETYPESHAPE"

Perhaps an IValueResolver would do the trick?  I've tried to specify a ValueResolver/IMemberValueResolver using ResolveUsing, but it's not obvious what to do.

I would like the ValueResolver to work on any generic object; the members of UglyXmlSoapObject are just generic objects, but the members always have a Value property.

```
 public class SoapXmlNaming : INamingConvention
        {

            static CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

            static TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

            public string SeparatorCharacter
            {
                get { return "_"; }
            }

            public Regex SplittingExpression { get; } = new Regex(@"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}0-9]+(?=_?)");

            public string ReplaceValue(Match match) =>
                textInfo.ToTitleCase(match.Value);


        }

  public class Poco
        {
            public String FirstName { get; set; }
            public String LastName { get; set; }
            public Decimal DeptTaxCalc { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you could customize your naming convention to work in a similar way the default [flattening](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Flattening.html) does.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  The solution is to use a custom formatter to extract the value, by registering a Custom formatter (implementation of ITypeConvert)  that is registered with the ConvertUsing method as follows:

```
public void Map(){
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateMap<Object, Object>().ConvertUsing<XmlPropertyConvert>();
    cfg.CreateMap<UglyXmlSoapObject, Poco>();
}

public class XmlPropertyConverter : ITypeConverter<Object,Object>{

public object Convert(object source, object destination, ResolutionContext context) {
    return GetValueObject(source)
}


private Object GetValueObject(Object member){
    var type = member.GetType();

    if (type.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("typeshape")){

    var property = type.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Value");
        if (property != null){
            var value = property.GetValue(member);
            return value;
        }

    }

    return member;

}

}
```

Comment: A limitation of this approach is that this only works in one direction, from UglyXmlObject -> Poco, not the other way.